# WSO2 as a Service Provider

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0

Does WSO2 support a use case wherein its a SAML service provider instead of being an Identity provider?
I want to do a sample use case where wso2 is the identity provider and another instance that is a service provider. Is it possible to use wso2 as a service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. It is possible, Because WSO2 Carbon product has an authentication framework that we can plug any authenticators. There is SAML2 SSO authenticator (Relying part) that can be plugged with Carbon server. You can find more details about it from WSO2 documentation from [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+Across+Different+Carbon+Servers)