# WSO2 Identity Server supports service provider initiated SSO in SAML?

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I found docs about IDP intitiated SSO in WSO2 IS. But haven't found anything about service provider initiated SSO.

Consider the scenario in which a local IS is used as a service provider which is connected to several externally hosted SAML IDP for outbound authentication.

Am I able to trigger a SP initiated login to one specific external IDP with a static link?  Ideally with a relay state attribute which is evaluated after successful SAML sign on process.

I am using WSO2 IS 5.0.0 - but hints for 5.1.0 would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IDP initiated login.

https://localhost:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=(Your SP Issuer ID)&fidp=(Your Home Realm Identifier if you have multiple IDP's)

https://localhost:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=myspissueid&fidp=myidp

OR
If you only have one IDP or don't need to skip selection page.
https://localhost:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=myspissueid

I believe if you get the fidp parameter in the SAML authnrequest then that will do the trick for the SP initiated one.

Answer (score 0):

considering IDP is running over localhost

**IDP init SSO** : https://localhost:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=**yourSPEntityName**

**SP init SSO**: https://localhost:9443/samlsso

Comment: Sorry, if my question wasn't clear. My scenario was about using WSO2 Identity Server as the service provider and a 3rd Party IDP as the Identity Provider.What you describe is using WSO2 IS as the IDP. Correct me. if I am wrong.

Comment: so you trying to configure Identity server as service provider and accept SAML token? so you check this https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+Across+Different+Carbon+Servers

check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588837/wso2-as-a-service-provider

Comment: Thanks for the links. But these links do not give answers to my questions for SP initiated login. I doubt that this works with IS.

Comment: Can you tell me how we can do IDP Initiated because when I access "https://localhost:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=yourSPEntityName", I got redirected to "https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_logout.do"